# Place a lock on a record when inserting in mysql during a transaction

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, transactions, locking

How do I place a shared or exclusive lock on a row that I am inserting into a table in MySQL?

I want to make sure that if I insert a row during a transaction another transaction can't then change or remove that row during the rest of the transaction.

Cheers!

Comment: It's your transaction, and until it's committed nobody else can see it, that's how transactions work, it's isolated until you're done. Are you trying to prevent your own code from modifying your own row?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I wanted to use the row I created in my transaction and make sure it couldn't be deleted from another transaction before I could use it, but of course it wouldn't be visible outside the transaction anyway until the commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to because nothing done in the transaction, including the creation of the record, will actually be visible outside of the transaction until the transaction has completed.

Answer (score 1):

Your table needs to use InnoDB or the equivalent.

You then do:

```
 START TRANSACTION;
 SELECT something FROM sometable WHERE somecolumn = somekey 
        FOR UPDATE;
```

You then modify the row in question.  Finally,

```
 COMMIT;
```

and you're done.

If you need consistent reading, you can use this instead:

```
 SELECT something FROM sometable WHERE somecolumn = somekey 
        LOCK IN SHARE MODE;
```

Comment: Thanks for this information. The problem was though that I forgot that the row wouldn't actually need locking as it wouldn't be visible to anyone else until the transaction was actually committed.